# PHP and AJAX update data to database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I'm trying to update a simple string to the database with `PHP` and `AJAX`.

Here is the code:

`HTML`

```
<form id="phoneNumberForm" class="form-inline" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2 align-content-center">
          <label for="phoneNumber" class="sr-only">Phone</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="phoneNumber_submit" id="phoneNumber_submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Save</button>
    <div id="phoneSuccess"></div>
</form>
```

`PHP`

```
if (isset($_POST['phoneNumber_submit'])) {
    $phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
    $profileEditAdmin = $db->query('UPDATE users SET user_phone = ? WHERE user_name = ?', $phoneNumber, $_SESSION['user_name']);
}
```

`AJAX`

```
$('#phoneNumberForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let phoneNumber = $('#phoneNumber').val();

    let $body = $("body");

    $(document).on({
         ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading"); },
         ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            phoneNumber:phoneNumber,
        },
        success: function() {
            $('#phoneSuccess').html('<p>Saved.</p>');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#phoneSuccess').fadeOut();
            }, 2000)
        }
    });
});
```

When I remove `preventDefault()` I get the entry in the database, but page is reloaded.

My goal is to have an entry in the database and to avoid page refreshing.

Comment: You do not have url parameter in your ajax code.

Comment: You will need it to request php page.

Comment: @Marko add `return false` at the end of submit event function, it will prevent to refresh your page.

Comment: @turivishal this is already achieved by `e.preventDefault()` - see https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: @ADyson thanks appreciated

Comment: The `url` is not needed, as others have suggested, if, at it seems, you are sending the request back to the same script - the value will default to the current page's URL, as per the jQuery docs. N.B. enctype="multipart/form-data" is also not needed on your form because a) it's only needed if you're uploading files, and b) you're uploading via AJAX anyway so this value will be ignored, you can just remove it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here your PHP looks for a variable called `phoneNumber_submit`:

```
if (isset($_POST['phoneNumber_submit'])) {
```

But here your AJAX sends only a variable called `phoneNumber`:

```
data: {
  phoneNumber:phoneNumber,
}
```

Clearly these two names do not match, so the `if` statement will never be true and the query will never run. It works when you submit the form without AJAX because you have `name="phoneNumber_submit"` on your submit button, so this value is sent to the server.

So you can either:

1) hard-code this value into your `data` parameter:

```
data: {
  "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
  "phoneNumber_submit": true
}
```

OR

2) just let jQuery do the work for you and use the [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function to get all the values and names you've already defined in your HTML and send them directly to the server, without you needing to specify each one again:

```
data: $(this).serialize()
```

Note: `this` in the above code will be your `<form>` element since you're handling the form's "submit" event.